# Silverlight 5 authentication

Tags: silverlight, membership

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and Silverlight 5. I created a Business Silverlight application. I am converting my asp.net app into Silverlight. I am using the same sql server database that the asp.net app uses. Both use Forms authentication. The membership tables are in my database prefixed with aspnet_. The asp.net app works fine. However it seems that by default the Silverlight app expects the tables to be named differently. aspnet_Users is Users now. I already have a table named Users and it is structured differently than aspnet_Users. When I try to login using the supplied Login framework it all fails because the columns are missing that it needs; like UserId. How can I make the authentication use the aspnet_* tables?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the schema is so different, could it be that you have changed the target to .Net 4.5?

An easy way to solve this problem is to implement a [Custom Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Then you can map to whatever schema you like.

The implementation is a little verbose, but it's pretty straight forward.